# Redirect root to subdirectory of current year if this exists, otherwise to a previous year that does exist

Tags: htaccess, redirects

This kind of htaccess code is a little complex for me as I'm just beginning to understand redirects with htaccess. Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` it's relatively straightforward to redirect to the "current year" if that year exists as a *physical directory* on the filesystem.

For example, you can do something like the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{TIME_YEAR} -d
RewriteRule ^$ /%{TIME_YEAR}/ [R=302,L]
```

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if already present in the file.

Note that this a temporary (302) redirect, so that the redirect is picked up when the "current year" changes.

**Problem...** redirecting to a "previous year" is not so trivial as you can't perform basic arithmetic in `.htaccess` alone to say `subtract 1 year` etc. For this you would need server-side access to create a `RewriteMap` that calls an external function. Or rewrite to a (PHP) script that is able to determine the correct year to redirect to.

However, this is presumably related to [your other question on the WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342203/htaccess-file-for-multiple-cmss-multisite-wordpress-wolfcms-on-same-domain). In which case is there a *physical directory* for years 2013 onwards?